Change the Package name easy way
when i change the middle part of package name, first part is not found is missing
example change example to word: com.example.test finish=> word.test "com" is missing from all files
com.example.test to com.word.test Not to word.test

this video watch: https://youtu.be/Jl4RDYNTJBc
